# How is definition of axiom of choice involving indexed family equivalent to the definition involving cartesian product?

Tags: definition, axiom-of-choice

There are two descriptions of axiom of choice that are considered equivalent.

The first one goes like this:

> Let $({X_i})_{i \mathop \in I}$ be an indexed family of sets all of which are non-empty, indexed by $I$ which is also non-empty.
>
> Then there exists an indexed family $({x_i})_{i \mathop \in I}$ such that
> $\forall i \in I: x_i \in X_i$

The second one goes like this:

> That is, the Cartesian product of a non-empty family of sets which are non-empty is itself non-empty.

I don't see how the second one is equivalent to the first one. Can someone illustrate with an example that both the descriptions mean the same thing?

Comment: Do you know the definition of an arbitrary Cartesian product?

Comment: I could probably add a few more duplicates. I found all of them by search "axiom of choice cartesian products". In the future, it is worth to spend a couple of minutes searching for the obvious search term before starting to write your question.